# Regex matching repeated pattern, one character followed by a whitespace

Tags: java, regex, character, space

I am trying build an input form which should allow a user to enter any number of letters followed by a whitespace (excluding the last letter entered).

For example:

```
a b c d e f= MATCHES
f g z b= MATCHES
aa bb cd efg= DOES NOT MATCH
ab c d e f g=DOES NOT MATCH
```

I currently have the following:

```
[a-zA-Z]\s+|[a-zA-Z]$
```

which does not seem to work.

Why does this not work/what I have done wrong?

Comment: You are trying to match any number of characters followed by a whitespace. And the last one in the example `ab c d e f g=DOES NOT MATCH`. This is confusing to me.

Comment: @ccf: It is only **one** character at a time.

Comment: @ccf: In `ab`, `a` is followed by `b`.

Comment: @noob: The title should be reworded like `Regex matching repeated pattern, one character followed by a whitespace`. Only myself got it wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

The regex should be `/^([a-z]\s)+[a-z]$/i`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ0uI9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\s)+[a-zA-Z]$
# anchor it to the beginning of the line
# non capturing group
# with ONE letter and ONE space unlimited times
# followed by exactly ONE letter and the end of the line ($)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fY2uF9/1) and make sure to use `MULTILINE` mode (for the anchors).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wanted to change the regex in any sort of way, but I did find a shorter regex that works with single characters followed by a space:

`/^\w\s$/`

Comment: Entire string should match.

Comment: In addition to @noob, `\s{1}` is redudant to `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this pattern:

```
^((?:[^ ] )+[^ ]?)$

REGEX EXPLANATION:

^       # assert line start
(       # capturing group starts
(?:     # 1st non-capturing group starts
[^ ]    # one non-space character
 )      # followed by a space; 1st non-capturing group ends
+       # repeat above pattern 1 or more times
[^ ]    # match a non-space character
?       # 0 or 1 time
)       # capturing group ends
$       # assert end of line
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uU5jO9/1)